# How to update many item in mongodb via MongoRepository?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

I got many items in mongodb with the structure like this

```
@Document
@Data
public class Config{

    @Id
    private String id;    
    private Date createDate; 
    private Date updateDate; 
    private Boolean active;  
    private String memo;   
}
```

Where the field `active` indicates whether the current config is active.

When any item needs to be actived (setting field `active` to `true`), the value `active` hold by the rest items  should be `false`. And the code I suppose shoud be like this:

```
    List<Config> configs = configRepo.findAll();
    configs.forEach(e->e.setActive(e.getId().equals("TARGET_CONFIG_ID")));
    configRepo.saveAll(configs);
```

The code above is slow as redundant IO operation exists. We can execute the code like this if the database were Mysql:

```
@Query("UPDATE CONFIG SET ACTIVE = ID == ?0")
```

Is any sub-class or method in MongoRepository can operate similar and update all items within one IO?

Comment: You can use `MongoTemplate` API methods to update data in the MongoDB database.

Comment: thanks a lot; I find 2 relative methods provided by MongoTemplate : findAndModify and updateMulti. The former one needs 2 seperate IO operations (fistly, set the active field  of old item to `false` and then modify the active one); And the rest method (`updateMulti`) looks no different with `saveAll` (the updated items needs to be fetched first).  Did I missed some awesome method?  :)

Comment: Update method has a filter and update. The filter finds the documents to be updated, and the update modifies the values of the specified fields.